# How to make a tree more compact?

Tags: trees

I'm using the `qtree` package, and I've made a tree that stretches far too much, and as a result, won't fit on the page. Here is my code:

```
\Tree [.1/1 [.1/2 [.1/3 [.1/4  [.1/5 1/6 2/9 ]   [.2/7 3/11 3/10 ]  ] [.2/5  [.3/8 4/11 7/12 ]   [.3/7 5/12 4/9 ]  ] ] [.2/3 [.3/5  [.4/7 5/9 7/12 ]   [.5/8 8/13 7/11 ]  ] [.3/4  [.5/7 7/10 8/11 ]   [.4/5 7/9 5/6 ]  ] ] ] [.2/1 [.3/2 [.4/3  [.5/4 6/5 9/7 ]   [.7/5 11/8 10/7 ]  ] [.5/3  [.8/5 11/7 13/8 ]   [.7/4 12/7 9/5 ]  ] ] [.3/1 [.5/2  [.7/3 9/4 12/5 ]   [.8/3 12/7 11/4 ]  ] [.4/1  [.7/2 10/3 11/3 ]   [.5/1 9/2 6/1 ]  ] ] ] ]
```

Is there a way to make lines from each node to the next smaller and spacing between everything smaller?

Thanks

Comment: And you should read the manual of `qtree`. In **'6 How do I . . . ? (The qtree FAQ)'**, the first question *'Make my tree fit in the page?'*

Answer (score 12):

You might also want to use [`tikz-qtree`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree) for this (syntax is the same):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\Tree [.1/1 [.1/2 [.1/3 [.1/4  [.1/5 1/6 2/9 ]   [.2/7 3/11 3/10 ]  ] [.2/5  [.3/8 4/11 7/12 ]   [.3/7 5/12 4/9 ]  ] ] [.2/3 [.3/5  [.4/7 5/9 7/12 ]   [.5/8 8/13 7/11 ]  ] [.3/4  [.5/7 7/10 8/11 ]   [.4/5 7/9 5/6 ]  ] ] ] [.2/1 [.3/2 [.4/3  [.5/4 6/5 9/7 ]   [.7/5 11/8 10/7 ]  ] [.5/3  [.8/5 11/7 13/8 ]   [.7/4 12/7 9/5 ]  ] ] [.3/1 [.5/2  [.7/3 9/4 12/5 ]   [.8/3 12/7 11/4 ]  ] [.4/1  [.7/2 10/3 11/3 ]   [.5/1 9/2 6/1 ]  ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Much easier with scale factor. Genius!

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,pdflscape}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
  \Tree [.1/1 [.1/2 [.1/3 [.1/4 [.1/5 1/6 2/9 ] [.2/7 3/11 3/10 ] ] [.2/5 [.3/8 4/11 7/12 ] [.3/7 5/12 4/9 ] ] ] [.2/3 [.3/5 [.4/7 5/9 7/12 ] [.5/8 8/13 7/11 ] ] [.3/4 [.5/7 7/10 8/11 ] [.4/5 7/9 5/6 ] ] ] ] [.2/1 [.3/2 [.4/3 [.5/4 6/5 9/7 ] [.7/5 11/8 10/7 ] ] [.5/3 [.8/5 11/7 13/8 ] [.7/4 12/7 9/5 ] ] ] [.3/1 [.5/2 [.7/3 9/4 12/5 ] [.8/3 12/7 11/4 ] ] [.4/1 [.7/2 10/3 11/3 ] [.5/1 9/2 6/1 ] ] ] ] ]%
}

\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\hspace*{-0.1\linewidth}\resizebox{1.2\linewidth}{!}{%
  \Tree [.1/1 [.1/2 [.1/3 [.1/4 [.1/5 1/6 2/9 ] [.2/7 3/11 3/10 ] ] [.2/5 [.3/8 4/11 7/12 ] [.3/7 5/12 4/9 ] ] ] [.2/3 [.3/5 [.4/7 5/9 7/12 ] [.5/8 8/13 7/11 ] ] [.3/4 [.5/7 7/10 8/11 ] [.4/5 7/9 5/6 ] ] ] ] [.2/1 [.3/2 [.4/3 [.5/4 6/5 9/7 ] [.7/5 11/8 10/7 ] ] [.5/3 [.8/5 11/7 13/8 ] [.7/4 12/7 9/5 ] ] ] [.3/1 [.5/2 [.7/3 9/4 12/5 ] [.8/3 12/7 11/4 ] ] [.4/1 [.7/2 10/3 11/3 ] [.5/1 9/2 6/1 ] ] ] ] ]%
}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```